# Incrementing a void pointer and operator precedence on C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, operator-precedence

Using pointers to build and access a generic data structure
where the size of elements is not fixes (thus cannot
use a structure).

The intriguing point comes on incrementing a `void *` pointer
that is casted as an `int *` to point to the next int.

First wrong approach was:

```
// I want to assign -1 to the two int elements the memory
// is pointing to
*(int *) next++ = -1;
*(int *) next = -1;
```

And this was wrong because `next++` does increment by one.

Probably there is more than one error confusing operator
precedence and assuming the increment to be done... anyway...

Even splitting the operation does not increment:

```c
*(int *) next = -1;
(int *)next++;  // does increment by one, maybe ++ comes before casting?
*(int *) next = -1;
```

Working example is:

```c
*(int *) next = -1;
next = (int *)next + 1;  // this increments by 4 as wanted
*(int *) next = -1;
```

But this puzzles me a bit as I don't see much difference
so I guess that there is some grammar rule that I am missing
and maybe some of you guys can give me a hint!

Comment: Skip the casting, assign to an `int*` variable to begin with and it instead.

Comment: C or C++? Different languages.

Comment: Currenty I am using C

Comment: I agree with the first comment.  If you know the variable type is `int *`, the better code would simply be at the first opportunity, to cast to an `int *`, and not write casts all over the place like this.  `int *ptrNext = (int *)next;` and simply use `ptrNext`.

Comment: I was always wondering what makes people write code that is hard to both write and read :-D

Comment: @bobah I am still learning C, so you can expect that I am pushing things to "non standard"

Comment: @piertoni - I did the learning part some time back too, conclusion I made for myself (mainly from economics point of view) is to make the code a bit more stupid than it has to be and use parentheses to specify the priority needed from an expression. Thus my previous comment and apologies it that sounded too direct, did not mean to.

Answer (score 3):

> The intriguing point comes on incrementing a `void *` pointer that is casted as an `int *` to point to the next int.

The first thing you must understand is that standard C (or C++) does not define increment or other arithmetic on pointers to `void` or to other incomplete types.  This is consistent with the fact that pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of the size / type of the pointed-to objects, and if the type of those objects is incomplete (as far as the type of a pointer-arithmetic operand goes) then there is not enough information to perform arithmetic with that pointer.

Some compilers, apparently including yours, implement an extension of treating pointer arithmetic with type `void *` as if the pointer had type `char *` instead.  Sometimes this is what one wants, but other times it is not.  I generally recommend avoiding any reliance on such extensions, and being sure to enable any compiler options necessary to get uses of it diagnosed at compile time.

> First wrong approach was:
>
> ```
> // I want to assign -1 to the two int elements the memory
> // is pointing to
> *(int *) next++ = -1;
> *(int *) next = -1;
> ```
>
> And this was wrong because `next++` does increment by one.

Yes, postfix `++` has higher precedence than cast operators, so `*(int *) next++ = -1` is interpreted as `*(int *)(next++) = -1`.  If the compiler accepts that then it is by virtue of the extension I describe above, so `next` is incremented to point to the next `char`, not the next `int`.

> Even splitting the operation does not increment:
>
> ```
> *(int *) next = -1;
> (int *)next++;  // does increment by one, maybe ++ comes before casting?
> *(int *) next = -1;
> ```

Yes, you have exactly the same operator precedence issue there as in the previous, but additionally, the cast in `(int *)next++` is useless because the result goes unused.

> Working example is:
>
> ```
> *(int *) next = -1;
> next = (int *)next + 1;  // this increments by 4 as wanted
> *(int *) next = -1;
> ```
>
> But this puzzles me a bit as I don't see much difference

Whereas the postfix `++` operator has higher precedence than cast operators, the addition operator (`+`) has lower precedence. Thus, `(int *)next + 1` is interpreted as `((int *)next) + 1`.  Because pointer arithmetic is done in terms of the pointed-to type, that produces a pointer to the next `int`.

Going back, then, to your purpose for doing this:

> Using pointers to build and access a generic data structure where the
> size of elements is not fixes

If such a system needs to know the size of the objects it is working with, so as to store them in an array, for instance, it usually carries that size either as an attribute of one or more of the data structures involved or as a parameter to the functions that require it.  A strictly conforming program that wants to perform the kind of increment you describe would then do so by casting to `char *`, maybe like so:

```
void *next_item(void *current_item, size_t item_size) {
    return ((char *) current_item) + item_size;
}
```

Although not actually necessary there, the parentheses make the operation precedence explicit, so as to avoid any confusion.

**Note**: the above is written for C.  The considerations are mostly the same for C++, but unlike C, C++ requires explicit casts for converting between `void *` and other pointer types.  (The absence of these in the original code implies that C is its true target language.)  The above example exhibits good code style for C, but would require the return value to be cast to `void *` to be used in C++.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. I am using `gcc` on a linux machine, I did not intent to use compiler extensions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform arithmetic with a pointer to `void`. The operator `++` has a higher precedence than `(type)` cast, so the `++` binds more tightly. So:

```
(int *) next++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
(int *) (next++);
```

and the cast's result is discarded.

Something like `((int *) next)++` (which is how you seem to want to get the precedence to happen) wouldn't work. The variable is an *lvalue*, something that can be assigned to. When you cast it, it becomes an *rvalue*, which you can't assign to, and of which you can't take the address.

Since you can't directly increment the `void *`, your only option (keeping it as a `void *`) is to do a plain `=` assignment to it:

```
next = (int *) next + 1
```

or with parentheses for complete clarity, at the cost of decreased ease to read:

```
next = ((int *) next) + 1
```

---

The best option is to just use an `int *` to begin with. If you need to keep flexibility with the variable type, just create a new variable:

```
int *next_int = next;
```

adding a cast only if you're in C++. (They're different languages, and have different rules.)

Comment: Nitpick: *postfix* `++` has higher precedence than cast operators, so associativity does not come into it.  All the postfix unary operators have highest precedence, then all the prefix unary operators, including casts, have the next tier.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good point, my eyes jumped to the first `++` they saw in the precedence table. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The `++` operator has higher precedence than the cast operator, so this:

```
(int *)next++;
```

Parses as:

```
(int *)(next++);
```

Adding parenthesis won't help:

```
((int *)next)++;
```

Because the `++` operator expects an *lvalue*, and the result of the cast operator is not an lvalue.

While `next = (int *)next + 1` is valid, the best way to handle this is to assign `next` to a variable of type `int *` and work with that.

```
int *nextInt = next;
*next++ = -1;
*next = -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
int* ip = some_void_pointer;
ip[0] = -1;
ip[1] = -1;
```

Or less elegantly:

```
int* ip = some_void_pointer;
*ip = -1;
ip++;
*ip = -1;
```

The issue in your code was related to operator precedence. Simply avoid mixing ++ with other operators in the same expression, because that is very bug-prone and can lead to numerous common bugs. Precedence issues, unsequenced access, order of evaluation dependencies and so on.

Comment: Thanks, simple and elegant!

Answer (score -2):

While not exactly for your case, I have written a small helper function that avoids some of the pitfalls in incrementing pointers:

```cpp
/// <summary>
/// Pointer arithmetic on byte level on other object types. This shall be used if the offset is in bytes, but T is some other pointer type.
/// </summary>
template <typename T>
T* AddBytes(T* inPtr, int offset)
{
    return (T*)(((byte*)inPtr) + offset);
}
```

Use like

```
   int value = *AddBytes((int*)startOfStruct, sizeof(int));
```

this gets the integer at byte offset 4 from the struct. (Nice: Works also on the left hand side of an assignment)

If you change this a bit, you could get increments by sizeof(int) instead:

```cpp
int* AddByInts(void* inPtr, int dwordCounts)
{
    return (int*)(((int*)inPtr) + offset);
}
```

Doesn't allow the use of the ++ operator directly, but may keep the code clearer than that, anyway.

Comment: This is only `C++` and not `C` I guess?

Comment: True, the template works for C++ only (the question is tagged both), but the last one should work for C as well.

Comment: "his gets the integer at byte offset 4 from the struct"  Eh? No, this code casts to an int pointer and then does pointer arithmetic on 4x4 = 16 bytes. None of this makes any sense to me. Besides that, keep things simple instead of needlessly complicated. Less bugs that way.

Comment: @Lundin No, it does not. Since the implementation casts to byte*, the offset is always in bytes. The cast on the first argument is to ensure T is of type int, which will be the type of the returned pointer.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood which version that was the solution. Anyway, this is super trivial stuff and not something we need to invent wrapper functions for.